# Why AlarmManager isn't working?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

This is the code in MainActivity's  onCreate() method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BatteryBroadcast.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 001,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, 1000, pendingIntent);
```

and this is BatteryBroadcast class

```
public class BatteryBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        Intent batteryIntent = context.registerReceiver(null, intentFilter);
        Log.i("B-TAG", batteryIntent.getStringExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL));
    }
}
```

but BatteryBroadcast class isn't working, why?

Comment: post the errors log

Answer (score 0):

You need add on the manifest the receiver:

```
<receiver
android:name"package.BatteryBroadcast"
android:enabled="true">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="unique_name"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

> And to call it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("unique_name");
sendBroadcast(intent)
```